# How to set Eslint to ignore specific files or cases

Tags: typescript, eslint, eslintrc

I want this setting `"no-unused-vars": "error"` to ignore TypeScript Declaration files (*.d.ts), function type declarations(`onChange: (new_value: string[]) => void;` "new_value"), and props marked with : _ (`async ({ page, created: _ })`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `.eslintrc.json` file you can specify which rules apply to which files

```json
{
  "root": true,
  "ignorePatterns": [],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.ts"],
      "parserOptions": {
        "project": ["tsconfig.json"]
      },
      "plugins": [],
      "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
      ],
      "rules": {
        // your default rules here
      }
    },
    {
      "files": ["*.d.ts"],
      "rules": {
        // Everything from *.ts rules above applies
        // but you can add or override individual rules here for *.d.ts files
        "no-unused-vars": "off"
      }
    },
    {
      "files": ["*.spec.ts"],
      "rules": {
        // Everything from *.ts rules above applies
        // but you can add or override individual rules here for *.spec.ts files
      }
    }
  ]
}
```